# Asp.net Website calling Service Stack webservice via JsonServiceClient and sending credit card number

Tags: c#

I have a Asp.net Website that is calling a Service Stack webservice via JsonServiceClient - code is BELOW.  note the request object contain the credit card number.  note the webservice is actually communicating with the bank credit card processing center.     Questions (1) is this secure enough considering credit card is in the object (2) or do i need to encrypt the payOrderREquest object prior to sending and then decrypt inside the webservice?

Thanks

CODE 
string svcVfbInsDataService = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["svcVfbInsDataService"];

```
        var route =
            VFB.Insurance.DataServices.DTO.DtoUtils.ServiceRoute.PayOrder.Route;
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(svcVfbInsDataService)
        {
            UserName = "ebizdataservice",
            Password = "vfbwebconsumpass1!"
        };

        //set up variables
        var sessionId = "abc6589658965898";
        var memNum = "379730";

        //build the request
        var payOrderRequest = new PayOrderRequest();
        payOrderRequest.SessionId = sessionId;
        payOrderRequest.CustomerNumber = memNum;
        payOrderRequest.OrderNumber = "895644551213";
        payOrderRequest.ccAddress1 = "4709 Mill Pond Drvie";
        payOrderRequest.ccCity = "Glen Allen";
        payOrderRequest.ccStateCode = "MS";
        payOrderRequest.ccPostalCode = "23060";
        payOrderRequest.ccName = "Donna Lawson";
        payOrderRequest.ccNumber = "4111111111111111";
        payOrderRequest.ccType = "VISA";
        payOrderRequest.ccExpMo = 12;
        payOrderRequest.ccExpYear = 2015;
        payOrderRequest.ccCvv = 678;


        PayOrderResponse ordResp = client.Post<PayOrderResponse>(route, payOrderRequest);
```

Comment: If you're posting to an `https:` url, it *should* be okay.  I assume you're not storing the CC info anywhere.

Comment: I am not storing cc info anywhere. the asp.net website is https... but the web service being called is not https.  Do think is ok or should i encrypt the dto prior to sending and then decrypt on webservice?  Or should the webservice be https also?  thanks so much for your response.

Comment: If the web service is not https, then the CC info is not secure.  You'll have to talk to the payment processor on how to encrypt in a way they can handle.

Comment: it's my webservice i can make it ssl.  i was just wondering if that was enough?  the payorderrequest can't be hacked if sent this way  if the receiving webservice site is ssl correct?  thanks again and have a great day.

Comment: Is it enough?  That's a loaded question.  Anytime you store the data, or move it around, it should be encrypted.  Yes, your webservice should use SSL.

Comment: let me explain a couple of things i forgot to mention.  1. the website and the webservice are on the same server.   i was thinking that since the code i posted calling the webservice is c# code from the website and is using jsonserviceclient to call the webservice (code calling is on the server,  the webservice is password authenticated) that this is secure enough.  I"m new to developing web services.  i don't mind encryt and decrypt if i really need to but i dont want to do it if not necessary.   thanks for your responses so far  and have a good weekend